# Rotating instance on a curve using Read > Curve Tangent

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, normals

I'm trying to make a tree using geometry nodes. I want to align my branches to the curve tangent, so that the branches point away from the bends in the trunk. I've got this far, but now I want to add a control to angle the branches up or down.

I think the issue is that although the Z axis of the branch is aligned to the curve tangent, the X and Y are aligned arbitrarily. Is there a way to align a second axis to be pointing away from the curve, so that I can then rotate the branch about the third?

Thanks for looking!

[image: Curve Tangent Example]

Comment: Do you try the "Normal" node to retrieve the normal to the curve ? It is controlled by the twist angle, so it could be adjusted in Edit Mode. Otherwise, you have to get the position of the control points before and after the current one to define with these 3 points a plane that is more or less locally "parallel" to the trunk. Its normal could be a candidate to rotate branches.